# Error when loading Hive table data to HBase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I'm using CDH 4.4, Hive-0.10.0, and HBase-0.94.6.  I created tables in hive using HBaseStorageHandler; I created a table called pokes which has one record, 98.  Here's my create table code:

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");
```

I verified the table was created in Hive (hbase_table_1) and in HBase (xyz).  However, when I run this command

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hbase_table_1
SELECT *
FROM pokes
WHERE foo=98;
```

I get an error:

> Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
>   MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
>   Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
>   Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

What am I missing?  Please help.

Comment: check the data you are trying to insert....if possible can you post the data here...

Comment: its just one record - 98, foo_98 (first col as int and second col as string)

Comment: i have also included .jar files in hive

Comment: task log gives the foll details -
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109) at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75) at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at

Comment: javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja

Comment: add the appropriate contrib jar add jar /opt/hive/lib/hive-contrib-<version>.jar.... let me know if this works....

Comment: it was already added and still not working. do v need to update core.xml file?